# Create PDA for the alphabet {a,b} starting and ending with the same symbol

Tags: pushdown-automata

I have to design PDA accepting language: set of strings over ∑ {a, b} starting and ending with the same symbol.
From that moment i think good way is to remember only first element because the last one should be the same, but how make push and pop properly to achieve the final state.
[image: What I have]

Comment: The language you describe seems to be regular, so you don't really need the stack.